# How do I insert data from a Panda into a SQLite3 DB by row?

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

Windows 10 Professional using PyCharm 2020.3 and Python 3.8

I am working on a problem set from one of my classes, we are supposed to create a SQLite3 DB with two tables using a SQL script, then read in an Excel spreadsheet that has multiple sheets. We only want certain data from certain sheets. The SQL script is:

```
CREATE TABLE "contractors"
  (
   "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   "GLOBAL_VENDOR_NAME" VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
  );
CREATE TABLE "actions"
  (
   "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   "DEPARTMENT" TEXT NOT NULL,
   "ACTIONS" INT NOT NULL,
   "DOLLARS" FLOAT NOT NULL,
   "CONTRACTOR_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (CONTRACTOR_ID) REFERENCES contractors(ID)
  );
```

Each sheet has 5 columns, "Global Vendor Name", "Number of Actions", "Dollars Obligated", "%Total Actions", "%Total Dollars". For the first table all I need is the Global Vendor Name. For the second table I just need the first three columns and then the sheet name is DEPARTMENT. I have the DB built and reading in the Excel file and iterating through the sheets is done. The issue I'm having is getting the data into the DB. My code is as such:

```
def build_db(con, cont, names, sql1, sql2):
    for i in names:
        try:
            temp = get_sheet(cont, i)
            insert_data(con, sql1, temp)
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
    return

def insert_data(con, sql_cmd, sheet):
    # Insert the data into the db. sql_cmd is a variable that holds the sqlite command
    if con is not None:
        c = conn.cursor()
    for k, row in sheet.iterrows():
        try:
            c.execute(sql_cmd, str(row[0]))
            con.commit()
        except:
            pass

insert_cont = """INSERT INTO contractors ('GLOBAL_VENDOR_NAME') VALUES (?); """
insert_act = """INSERT INTO actions ('DEPARTMENT', 'ACTIONS', 'DOLLARS', 'CONTRACTOR_ID') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?); """
build_db(conn, contract, sheet_names, insert_cont, insert_act)
```

The code runs but no data is showing up in the 'contractors' table (I'm only trying to get data into the contractors table before moving on to the 'actions' table). I know you can insert whole columns (even though I couldn't get that to work) but I have to insert by row because I will have to check each Global Vendor Name to make sure its only been inserted once into the 'contractors' tables. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: This line `c.execute(sql_cmd, str(row[0]))` gives an error. It isn't thrown because of the `try` block. Reason for the error: The second argument to `execute` is a tuple, this is sending a string. How to see the error: Capture with

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Suspect it's complaining that x parameters sent, expecting 1 where x is the length of `str(row[0])`.